# Setup custom domain to Azure Document DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I want to create a azure document DB under staging subscription, in future i'll be moving that DB to production subscription but i need to create that document DB with custom domain name .

say for example, by default the document DB URI will be xxx.documents.azure.com:443, but i need the it is xxxx.mydomain.com:443, Is that possible, if so how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You could set up your own proxy to accomplish this. Other than that, I do not know of a way to do that but in general this is not needed because DocumentDB is designed to be hit by your application server not the end user. Under these circumstances, it poses no issue for the url to be ...azure.com.

If we understood why you wanted this, we might be able to help you accomplish that goal some other way.